# Run exe. file in Python API

Tags: python, subprocess, python-requests

I am currently writing a python script for Plaxis which uses remote API Python environment.
I am wondering whether I can run exe. file in my local computer in the API environment. I have tried the usual way of running a exe.file in Python script, but it did not succeed. Thank you so much for your help!
Here is my code:

```
from plxscripting.easy import *
s_i, g_i = new_server('localhost', 10000, password='123456')

i = "1"

a = int(16)

b = int(16)

address= "E:\\python practics\\test" + str(i) + ".p2dx"


g_i.save(address)

g_i.gotostages()

import subprocess

RmdNumGen = "E:\\python practics\\random numebr generator.exe"

process = subprocess.Popen(RmdNumGen, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)

p.communicate(a,b)

g_i.InitialPhase.ShouldCalculate = True
g_i.Phase_1.ShouldCalculate = True

g_i.calculate()

exit()
```

Comment: What do you mean “it did not succeed”? Please be more specific.

Comment: I figured it out. It is something wrong with my import subprocess code.

Comment: And I want to pass the two variable a, b(integer) to the exe.file. But the code failed. May I know how can I correct it? Thank you!

Comment: The code is :
import subprocess

RmdNumGen = "E:\\python practics\\random numebr generator.exe"

process = subprocess.Popen(RmdNumGen, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)

p.communicate(a,b)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the use of popen, but there is a clear mistake in the code:
Try with process.communicate instead of p.communicate

Are you dealing with some kind of probabilistic FORM analysis in Plaxis? There are several thesis about that.